# angular 2 ngClass binding not working after animation

Tags: angular

Having this code:

```
<ul>
  <li routerLinkActive="is-active"><a routerLink="/user/register"><span>registration</span></a></li>
  <li routerLinkActive="is-active"><a routerLink="/user/login"><span>login</span></a></li>
  <li role="menu" class="drop-down">
    <a class="drop-down--toggle" (click)="toggle()">
      <span class="flag-icon" [ngClass]="_currentLocale.flag"></span> 
    </a>
    <ul [@stateAnimation]="dropDownState" (@stateAnimation.done)="dropDownAnimEnd($event)" class="drop-down--menu">
      <li *ngFor="let locale of _localeMenu" (click)="change(locale)">
        <a>
          <span class="flag-icon" [ngClass]="locale.flag"></span>
          <span>{{locale.name}}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I managed to have everything working except this line:

```
<span class="flag-icon" [ngClass]="_currentLocale.flag"></span>
```

When a new locale is selected from the drop-down menu then the menu is closed first and the locale is changed. After that the current locale and locale menu is updated. But the current locale flag does not get updated till I toggle the menu again. In Safari seems to work but not in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Update: this is the LocaleModel:

```
export class LocaleModel {
  id: number;
  code: string;
  name: string;
  fileName: string;
  flag: string;

  constructor(id: number, code: string, name: string, fileName: string, flag: string) {}
}
```

Comment: what is `_currentLocale.flag`? is it a class name or a variable?

Comment: _currentLocale.flag is a string -> "flag-icon-es"

Comment: Sorry, can't tell. Perhaps with a Plunker to reproduce.

Comment: sorry, could not help. feels like ` _currentLocale` does not set properly when locale is changed.

Comment: created this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/soCWD9i3YKsUrRHZ5WLk?p=preview and there seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit seems to be [this resolved animation bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12707), which failed to update the binding after the animation end. Safari could have been working because it was using [the polyfill](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js) as it is not supporting the [Web Animations API](https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/), info found [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation).